# Timeout when trying to create any terraform resource on localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, localstack

I am trying to set up localstack environment for lambda, but I can not create any resource. I used the official guide from https://github.com/localstack/localstack but every resource I try to create when perform terraform apply I got timeouts from the services.

Below I included example docker-compose and main.tf files which try to create s3 bucket. Also I tried to run examples from some github repositories and I also have this timeout problem.

Generally I see that localstack services are healthy and I can access them via for AWS cli. But I am stuck and do not know where the problem is.

**access s3 via cli**

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3api list-buckets

{
    "Buckets": [],
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "webfile",
        "ID": "bcaf1ffd86f41161ca5fb16fd081034f"
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - "4571:4571"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES- }
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

**main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "123"
  secret_key = "xyz"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_requesting_account_id = true
  skip_metadata_api_check = true
  s3_force_path_style = true
  endpoints {
    s3 = "http://localhost:4572"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "demo-bucket-terraform"
  acl    = "private"
}
```

```
terraform apply

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_s3_bucket.b will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
      + acceleration_status         = (known after apply)
      + acl                         = "public-read"
      + arn                         = (known after apply)
      + bucket                      = "demo-bucket-terraform"
      + bucket_domain_name          = (known after apply)
      + bucket_regional_domain_name = (known after apply)
      + force_destroy               = false
      + hosted_zone_id              = (known after apply)
      + id                          = (known after apply)
      + region                      = (known after apply)
      + request_payer               = (known after apply)
      + website_domain              = (known after apply)
      + website_endpoint            = (known after apply)

      + versioning {
          + enabled    = (known after apply)
          + mfa_delete = (known after apply)
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_s3_bucket.b: Creating...
aws_s3_bucket.b: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_s3_bucket.b: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_s3_bucket.b: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
aws_s3_bucket.b: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
aws_s3_bucket.b: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
.
.
.
```

Comment: Why do you use port 4566 in your working awscli example, but use port 4572 for terraform?

Comment: hey, I changed the port to 4566 on s3 in terraform and it works. So probably I have to use this port for all the services, because in docker they are all exposed via 4566. Strange that all the examples I run are wrong and the official one did not mentioned this case. Propably because they were not intended for docker?

Comment: They do say in the official documentation: https://github.com/localstack/localstack somewhere at the beginning and on the announcements: `2020-09-15: A major (breaking) change has been merged in PR #2905 - starting with releases after v0.11.5, all services are now exposed via the edge service (port 4566) only! Please update your client configurations to use this new endpoint.` 
it's "quite new" and so far all the tutorials I've found about localstack are out of date...